# Javascript float addition

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var w = 0;
 var weight1 = parseFloat("0.6");
 var weight2 = parseFloat("0.3");
 w = weight1 + weight2;

 document.write("total weight: " + w);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why does this print 0.8999999999999999  and not 0.90000000

Comment: Welcome to floating point numbers!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036662/weird-javascript-behaviour-floating-point-addition-giving-the-wrong-answer

Comment: Welcome to IEEE 754 floating point numbers, that is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the number 9/10 cannot be represented cleanly in base 2, just like the number 1/3 cannot be cleanly represented in base 10.

Answer (score 1):

Source of the problem:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/42980

Workarounds:

[Is there a definitive solution to javascript floating-point errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831687/is-there-a-definitive-solution-to-javascript-floating-point-errors)

[How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/682011-solution-floating-point-errors

Answer (score 0):

The way floating point numbers are made, certain values cannot be accurately represented. This is a limitation of this data type, there is little to nothing you can do to fix it, you have to just anticipate this, and make use of round or something.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 0):

Simple rounding errors. floating point numbers are not precise. This makes comparisons a little more complicated. Eg. If (my_float == 3.0) will invariably fail.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question - floating points have as much precision as your RAM can allow. If you create a floating number 1 - it may actually be 1.000000000000000000001

Obviously your solutions include rounding the number, or using ints

Comment: This has nothing to do with RAM, and specifying the exact float value 1 will never yield anything but 1.  This has to do with repeating numbers -- just like 1/3 can't be represented as a finite digit sequence in base 10, the number 1/10 cannot be represented as a finite digit sequence in base 2.

Comment: I was definitely wrong on that one. here's what I tested, and concluded incorrectly:

    ((1/10) * 1e63) - 1e62 = 1.141798154164768e+46