# how to truncate the float value in javascript

Tags: javascript, truncate, parsefloat

We want to display dynamic value in a table using JavaScript in vb.net. we have define the variable as var `rValue`.

The expression is `rValue = parseFloat(594 * 0.1);`

We are getting putput as `59.400000000000006` but we need the output as `59.4` please let us know how to do that .

P.S. We do not want to use `tofixed()` as it will return the two decimal point for all the values which do not have decimal points.

Comment: "`[toFixed()] will return the two decimal point`"??? In which browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a definitive solution to javascript floating-point errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831687/is-there-a-definitive-solution-to-javascript-floating-point-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Use the native `toPrecision()` method:

```
 <script>   
 var rValue = new Number(59.400000000000006 );
 var n = rValue.toPrecision(3);
 //n will be 59.4 
 </script>
```

Comment: What if `rValue >= 100`?

Answer (score 1):

Use  `rValue = parseFloat(594 * 0.1).toFixed(2)` and if the decimal is .00 remove the decimal places.

e.g.

```
var num=rValue.split('.')[1];
        if(num==='00')
        {
         rValue=rValue.split('.')[0];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var rValue = parseFloat(594 * .2);
alert(rValue.toFixed(2).replace(".00",""))
```

[here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zhqcc/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from [0.1 not being able to be represented in binary](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/). It actually has an infinite number of decimals, hence every arithmetic operation with this number results in the output being approximate.

You can either opt to use division by a float 10 instead:

```
var rValue = 594 / 10.0;
```

or, if this kind of truncation is a recurring issue, you can write a utility function:

```
/**
* @param {Number} value
* @param {Integer} precision
* @returns {Number}
*/
var truncateFloat = function(value, precision) {
    // Ensure the multiplier is a float
    var pMult = 1.0;
    while (precision--) {
        pMult *= 10;
    }
    // Multiply the value by the precision multiplier, 
    // convert it to int (discarding any pesky leftover decimals) 
    // and float-divide it by the same multiplier
    return ((value * pMult) >> 0) / pMult;
}
```

Hope this helps a little! :)

Answer (score 0):

easy arrow function:

```
const truncate = (number,decimals) =>
Math.trunc(number*Math.pow(10,decimals)) / Math.pow(10,decimals)
```

Answer (score -2):

Like This ?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rValue As String = 56.40000000006
    Dim charVal() As Char = rValue.ToCharArray()
    Dim getVal As String = Nothing
   '----------Change for decimal places---------
    Dim decimalPlaces As Integer = 2
    Dim decimalPlace As Integer = -1
    Dim realValue As Double = 0
    For Each Val As Char In charVal

        If Char.IsDigit(Val) Then
            getVal &= Val
        Else
            getVal &= "."
        End If

        If getVal.Contains(".") Then
            decimalPlace += 1
        End If

        If decimalPlace = decimalPlaces Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(realValue)
End Sub
```